# Secure a server - Raid-5 encrypted with BitLocker?

Tags: encryption, windows-server-2008-r2, disk-encryption, bitlocker, raid-5

I look after a small office, and when I say small I mean SMALL.

The have a 2008R2 Windows Server running a domain and shares for about 10 people. They handle some pretty sensitive information so security is an issue however their location does not allow for the servers physical security so I have been tasked with finding a way to make sure their data is protected if physically removed from the premises.

They have 3 x 1TB drives in a RAID-5 array that sits on a decent Asus motherboard (not server hardware!)

My 1st thought was to use TrueCrypt but I was a little bit uncertain in using a 3rd party tool so looking at BitLocker at the moment.

Can anyone point out any pitfalls in using BitLocker to encrypt a RAID-5 array? I've read that there is a performance overhead but I think the security will overweigh in terms of importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitlocker has a pretty low overhead.  Most likely you wont notice it in a file server environment.

I havent used BitLocker on a RAID array before, but it shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Keltari, Do you know if this can cause any instability in the array itself? in case it needs to repair or if a drive fails and needs to be changed?

Comment: If its a hardware RAID, it doesnt know or care whats on it.  If its a Windows RAID, it still shouldnt matter.